# Почему возникает ошибка QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record?

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Есть такой код:

```
static unsigned CountUpload = 0;
// получаем данные из БД
Query.exec("SELECT * FROM Channels LIMIT 10 OFFSET " + static_cast<QString>(10 * CountUpload));
// увеличиваем счетчик сделанных запросов
CountUpload++;
Query.next();
qDebug() << Query.value(0).toString();
```

Его смысл в том, что при запросе клиенту отсылаются очередные 10 каналов из БД.
Ради теста я вывожу 0-е поле первой записи в консоль, но мне выдает ошибку, описанную в заголовке.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static_cast<QString>(10 * CountUpload)` очень странная запись, я бы ее заменил на `QString::number(10 * CountUpload)`.

Еще у вас нет проверки успешности выполнения запроса, скорее всего, запрос в базу получился кривым и ответ получился неуспешный, поэтому при обращении к данным ответа у вас ошибка

Смотрите на описание методов, каждый из них возвращает булевый признак успеха выполнения:

- [bool QSqlQuery::exec(const QString &query)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#exec)
- [bool QSqlQuery::next()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#next)

Если запрос не был успешным, то вызовите [QSqlError QSqlQuery::lastError() const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastError), чтобы узнать текст ошибки